# React state updating but not mapping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using redux to manage my state and I can see that it is updating correctly judging from devtools and I can also console log it with `this.props.myobj`.

However if I try to map through it with `this.props.myobj` then I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

If i try to map it with `this.state.myobj` then it remains blank.

Just to reiterate I'm using redux, mapstatetoprops, and can see that the state both in redux and in the component is being updated and set correctly.

Comment: Could you upload it to a jsfiddle or something so that we can take a look?

Comment: Post your code please. It is hard to tell without the code.

Comment: First console "this.props" and if myobj is there in your props then use "this.props.myobj && this.props.myobj.map()" as props won't be there in the initial state of rendering so it throws the error. Console.log will help you getting clarified about the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this.props.obj is not available in the first render. Try `{ this.props.obj && this.props.obj.map(()=>{}) }`